# How to linearize this?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to understand how he arrived at that equation in the end or at least how to linearize

For the two- dimensional nonstationary incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in a smooth bounded domain  , with non-slip Dirichlet boundary conditions, we can write them as an abstract initial value problem.

$u_t+\nu Au+B(u,u)=f,\quad u(0)=u_0$

The Stokes operator A is defined by $−P\Delta$, where P is the Leray orthogonal.

The nonlinear term B(u, u) is defined in general by $B(u, v) = P [(u · ∇)v]$.

$b(u,u,\phi)$ is defined as $(B(u, u),\phi)$ taking the inner product on $L^2$ with $\phi$.

On the paper i`m reading the autor is trying to obtain a estimative in $L^2$

He says:

"In order to give our analysis for the error $u − u_m$ with L2 -norm, we begin with a technical result concerning backward-in-time linearized Navier-Stokes equations which is similar to that used by Heywood & Rannacher [15] and Hill & Suli [16]. For any given s ∈ (0,T] and g ∈ L2(0,s;Y), the backward problem is to find  $\phi(t)∈Hm$ such that for $0<t <s$
\begin{equation}
(v, \phi_t)−a(v,\phi)−b(v,u,\phi)−b(u,v,\phi)=(v,g)
\end{equation}
, ∀v∈Hm, (3.11)
with  $\phi(s) = 0$. It is easy to show that the problem (3.11) is well-posed and has a

How should i proceed in the same way to linearize a term like $(u\cdot\nabla)\omega$
i'm trying to obtain a formula like this on above for this equation.
\begin{equation}
\omega_t+K_1\Delta\omega+B(u,\omega)=K_2\ rot\ \omega+g
\end{equation}

any reference?

Comment: Your reference seems to truncate at an odd point. Care to provide the rest?